# Is there a way to change error_logger tty output format

Tags: erlang

Is there way to change the format error_logger print messages to the console, or file.

I get

```
=INFO REPORT==== 8-Jun-2011::18:46:15 ===
This is my info report.
```

I want to get this

```
INFO:8-Jun-2011::18:46:15: This is my info report.
```

Example is for info, but it should be for error, warning etc

Answer (score 5):

SASL `error_logger` is ordinary OTP event manager so you can register and remove any `gen_event` handler as you want there.